# Passing data in the body of a DELETE request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have two Spring MVC controller methods. Both receive the same data in the request body (in the format of an HTLM `POST` form: `version=3&name=product1&id=2`), but one method handles `PUT` requests and another `DELETE`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "ajax/products/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public MyResponse updateProduct(Product product, @PathVariable("id") int productId) {

//...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "ajax/products/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseBody
public MyResponse updateProduct(Product product, @PathVariable("id") int productId) {

//...
}
```

In the first method, all fields of the `product` argument are correctly initialised. In the second, only the `id` field is initialised. Other fields are `null` or 0. (`id` is, probably, initialised because of the `id` path variable).

I can see that the `HttpServletRequest` object contains values for all fields in the request body (`version=3&name=product1&id=2`). They just are not mapped to the fields of the `product` parameter.

How can I make the second method work?

I also tried to use the `@RequestParam` annotated parameters. In the method that handles `PUT` requests, it works. In the `DELETE` method, I get an exception: `org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'version' is not present`.

I need to pass data in the body of `DELETE` requests because the data contain a row version which is used for optimistic locking.

Comment: Are you using Tomcat?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The problem is not a `Spring` problem, but a `Tomcat` problem.

By default, Tomcat will only parse arguments that are in the form style, when the HTTP method is `POST` (at least for version 7.0.54 that I checked but it's probably the same for all Tomcat 7 versions).

In order to be able to handle DELETE methods as well you need to set the `parseBodyMethods` attribute of the Tomcat Connector. The connector configuration is done in `server.xml`.

Your updated connector would most likely look like:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           parseBodyMethods="POST,PUT,DELETE"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

[Here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/ajp.html) is documentation page for configuring Tomcat connectors.

Once you setup Tomcat to parse the parameters, Spring will work just fine (although in your case you will probably need to remove `@RequestBody` from the controller method)

Comment: Thanks! It explains my problem. I will upvote this answer when I get 3 more points of reputation. But I would rather pull the `version` from `HttpServletRequest` directly than mess up with Tomcat configuration files.

Comment: No problem! The problem is that you wont be able to pull `version` from `HttpServletRequest.getParameter` either since Tomcat has never populated the necessary data structures with that info.

Comment: Also changing the connector in `server.xml` is really no big deal. Probably all you will want to do is add `parseBodyMethods="POST,PUT,DELETE"` (or change it if it already exists)

Comment: I am currently using the `request.getInputStream()` method for debugging. Not an elegant solution, but it works :)

Comment: @Alex Yes that will definitely work :). But it would probably be best of you avoid it :) :)

Comment: In the end, I used the following solution: I added `@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> formData` parameter to the controller method, and then got the `version` field: `String version = formData.get("version").get(0)`. For this to work, `FormHttpMessageConverter` should be registered. This message converter is registered by default if Java Config or `<mvc:annotation-driven />` tag is used. I'll wait a bit for comments from others, and then will accept this answer if nobody says anything new.

Comment: What about HttpPutFormContentFilter?

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding the annotation @RequestBody to your Product argument.

But if you just need to pass version information, using a request param is more appropriate.

So add a new argument in your delete method @RequestParam("version") int version, and when calling the delete method pass a query param like `..ajax/products/123?version=1`

As you said request param is not working for you in delete, can you post the exact url you used and the method signature ?

Comment: I cannot pass the version in the URL, because I have to keep my URLs RESTful. My request body looks like this: `version=3&name=product1&id=2` (it's the format of a POST HTML form I think).

Comment: There is a reason why I do not use `@RequestBody` in my `PUT` and `POST` controller methods: using no `@RequestBody` makes processing data binding errors more simple (you can process them the same way as validation errors). Data binding errors are errors that happen when you put a string in an integer field, for example.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, `@RequestBody` would bind the incoming form to the `product` object with a "message converter", and any data binding error would result in a hard-to-process exception (at least it's the case when you use `@RequestBody` for JSON data). On the other hand, I do not need to worry about data binding errors for the `DELETE` method, so I will try to use `@RequestBody`.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the `@RequestBody` annotation. However, it looks like there is no message converter that can convert an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form to a Product object (I found only a message converter for `MultiValueMap<String, String>`). So, I think, for `@RequestBody Product product` to work, I would have to write my own message converter.

Answer (score 2):

Spring boot 1.5.*

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(){
        @Override
        protected void customizeConnector(Connector connector) {
            super.customizeConnector(connector);
            connector.setParseBodyMethods("POST,PUT,DELETE");
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for spring boot 2.0+ :

```
@Bean
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory containerFactory() {
    return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void customizeConnector(Connector connector) {
            super.customizeConnector(connector);
            connector.setParseBodyMethods("POST,PUT,DELETE");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi,  java_pickle , welcome to Stack Overflow. Some explanation with the answer is very much appreciable. It will help to understand the objective of code. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Passing data in the body of a DELETE request

@Component
public class CustomiseTomcat implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer {

```
@Override
public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {

    factory.addConnectorCustomizers( new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Connector connector) {
            connector.setParseBodyMethods("POST,PUT,DELETE");
        }
    });
}
```

}