# How use PUT method in Springboot Restcontroller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Am developing an application using Spring boot.I tried with all representations verbs like GET, POST , DELETE all are working fine too. By using PUT method, it's not supporting in spring boot. Whether I need to add any new configuration.

Put method works only the request not have any parameters. If i add any query parameter or form data it doesnt work. Kindly any expertize will help me to solve this issue.

```
@RequestMapping("/student/info")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody String updateStudent(@RequestParam(value = "stdName")String stdName){
    LOG.info(stdName);
    return "ok";
}
```

> Request method 'PUT' not supported

Comment: What version of Spring are you working with? And what does the URL look like that "doesn't work" ?

Comment: Spring boot 1.1.1  and URL is like this http://localhost:8000/student/info?stdName=test

Comment: You have 2 request mappings for a single method merge them into a single one. `@RequestMapping(value="/student/info", method=RequestMethod.PUT)`. Next to that you probably also need to add the  `HttpPutFormContentFilter` to yuor list of filters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**This code will work fine. You must specify request mapping in class level or in function 
level.**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/student/info", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody String updateStudent(@RequestBody Student student){
 LOG.info(student.toString());
 return "ok";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following Request Mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/student/info", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
```

There's no need to separate the value and the Request Method for the URI.

Comment: @AravindCheekkallur what version of Spring are you using and have you added the filter `HttpPutFormContentFilter`. Also, have you got  your Boot configuration Java class - it should have `@EnableAutoConfiguration`

Answer (score 0):

Since Spring 4.3 you can use `@PutMapping("url")` : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PutMapping.html

In this case it will be:

```
@PutMapping("/student/info")
public @ResponseBody String updateStudent(@RequestParam(value = "stdName")String stdName){
    LOG.info(stdName);
    return "ok";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same issue with spring boot 1.5.*,I fixed it by follow:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/nick", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public Result updateNick(String nick) {
    return resultOk();
}
```

Add this bean

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(){
        @Override
        protected void customizeConnector(Connector connector) {
            super.customizeConnector(connector);
            connector.setParseBodyMethods("POST,PUT,DELETE");
        }
    };
}
```

see also

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25383378/4639921
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47300174/4639921

Answer (score -1):

you can add @RestController annotation before your class.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/range")
public class RangeRestController {
}
```