# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'PUT' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following controller:

```
@RestController
public class RestaurantController {
    @Autowired
    RestaurantService restaurantService;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/restaurant/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Restaurant>> listAllRestaurants() {
        System.out.println("Fetching all restaurants");
        List<Restaurant> restaurants = restaurantService.findAllRestaurants();
        if(restaurants.isEmpty()){
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Restaurant>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Restaurant>>(restaurants, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/restaurant/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<Restaurant> updateRestaurant(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestBody Restaurant restaurant) {
        System.out.println("Updating Restaurant " + id);

        Restaurant currentRestaurant = restaurantService.findById(id);

        if (currentRestaurant==null) {
            System.out.println("Restaurant with id " + id + " not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<Restaurant>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        currentRestaurant.setName(restaurant.getName());
        currentRestaurant.setDescription(restaurant.getDescription());
        currentRestaurant.setIcon(restaurant.getIcon());

        restaurantService.updateRestaurant(currentRestaurant);
        return new ResponseEntity<Restaurant>(currentRestaurant, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Here is my calls from the PostMan.
First I am making the GET call to get all the restaurants and it works fine
[image]
Second I am trying to update the object by I am getting the following error.
[image]
At the Tomcat 8.0.32, I am getting the following log:

> 13-Feb-2016 16:55:09.442 WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-9]
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
>   Request method 'PUT' not supported

I don't understand this is how possible.
And here is my dependencies:

```
<properties>
        <springframework.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springsecurity.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
        <jackson.version>2.6.3</jackson.version>
        <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
        <testng.version>6.9.4</testng.version>
        <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.187</h2.version>
        <dbunit.version>2.2</dbunit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jsr303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Joda-Time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Need this for json to/from object -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>${dbunit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

If more information is needed please tell me! Thanks.

Edit 1:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("bill").password("user").roles("USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("dba").password("dba").roles("ADMIN","DBA");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/home","/restaurant/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/list").access("hasRole('USER')")
        .antMatchers("/list").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
        .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
        .and().csrf()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /restaurant/1 at
>   position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter:
>   'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
>
> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 DEBUG
>   FilterChainProxy:324 - /restaurant/1 at position 2 of 12 in additional
>   filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
>
> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:159 -
>   No HttpSession currently exists
>
> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 DEBUG
>   HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:101 - No SecurityContext was
>   available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
>
> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /restaurant/1 at
>   position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter:
>   'HeaderWriterFilter'
>
> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:128 -
>   Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@3ded3d8a
>
> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /restaurant/1 at
>   position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter:
>   'CsrfFilter'
>
> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 DEBUG CsrfFilter:106 - Invalid CSRF
>   token found for
>   http://localhost:8080/SpringSecurityCusotmLoginFormAnnotationExample/restaurant/1
>
> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:861 - DispatcherServlet
>   with name 'dispatcher' processing PUT request for
>   [/SpringSecurityCusotmLoginFormAnnotationExample/Access_Denied]
>
> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:294 - Looking
>   up handler method for path /Access_Denied
>
> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 DEBUG
>   ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver:134 - Resolving exception from
>   handler [null]:
>   org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException:
>   Request method 'PUT' not supported
>
> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 DEBUG
>   ResponseStatusExceptionResolver:134 - Resolving exception from handler
>   [null]:
>   org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException:
>   Request method 'PUT' not supported
>
> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 DEBUG
>   DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:134 - Resolving exception from handler
>   [null]:
>   org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException:
>   Request method 'PUT' not supported
>
> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 WARN 
>   PageNotFound:198 - Request method 'PUT' not supported
>
> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:337 -
>   SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not
>   be stored in HttpSession.
>
> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 DEBUG
>   DispatcherServlet:1034 - Null ModelAndView returned to
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter
>   completed request handling
>
> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 DEBUG
>   DispatcherServlet:996 - Successfully completed request
>
> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:248 - Returning cached
>   instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
>
> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:337 -
>   SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not
>   be stored in HttpSession.
>
> 2016-02-14 12:30:56 DEBUG
>   SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:105 - SecurityContextHolder now
>   cleared, as request processing completed

Comment: It sounds like the PUT verb has been disabled by Apache Tomcat.  Do a Google search on disabling PUT in Apache Tomcat and you will see many posts that talk about disabling.  You can then see if any of these setting exist (a) in you app, or more likely (b) in your Apache Tomcat settings.

Comment: @EJK it is also have to do something with my Spring Security Config?

Comment: @EJK I have try an another wepapp with PUT, DELETE, and it is working!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try turning up the logging level for `org.springframework.web` to `DEBUG`. This will give you some insight into how Spring is trying to deal with the request. Hopefully, it will give you (or us) some more clues on how to fix it.

If you're using Spring Boot, just add this line to your *application.properties* file:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

*Edit after seeing additional logging:*

The 'PUT' not supported message is a bit misleading. The real problem comes before that. You don't have a valid CSRF token. How are you submitting the request? It looks like you are using the *PostMan* tool (but I am not familiar with this tool) rather than submitting the form directly from a web-page. There may be some way that you can add the token to your request using the tool. Does it work without the tool - submitting the form directly from the web-page?

Comment: Yes, you are right! I did it from the web-page and follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27834867/spring-security-csrf-token-not-working-with-ajax. And now I am getting 400 bad request!

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. In my case, I forgot to attach "@ResponseBody" on the controller. Silly mistake :^(

Comment: After a lot of searching I finally realized what caused the error on a similar issue I experienced. Apparently the whole CORS problem was caused by my own mistake and the advice for allowing this logging made it possible for me realize this. Great answer.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same error but for me it was caused by the fact that I had ommited the ID as URL parameter. I ommited it because the ID was present in the JSON body.

When I changed .../restaurant to ...restaurant/1, the error went away.

Comment: LOL - thanks for the reminder progonkpa to start with the small stuff. I had a null ID.

Comment: I had a similar issue. My Put request url was `/task/update` with a complete json object in the `RequestBody`, changed it to `/task/{id}` and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 4):

I worked with a basic CRUD application in Spring Boot. In PUT mapping, I passed the path variable in the wrong way.

@PutMapping(path ={"studentId"}) replaced to @PutMapping(path ="{studentId}")

Comment: This was exactly the issue I faced! Now I realize this could be a common mistake for beginners. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By default, in `WebMvcAutoConfiguration`, `HttpPutFormContentFilter` is not configured and hence the issue.

Its fixed in spring boot `[1.3.0)` version and working fine. So, you may try updating your spring-boot version or configure this filter manually to make things work.

[Issue reference](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3643). 
[Another Stackoverlow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625902/how-use-put-method-in-springboot-restcontroller)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

So this Basically happens because of the **missing parameters in the URL or the wrong URL.**

In My case, I was forgetting the " **id** "i.e "1" param in my URL.

Solution: http://localhost:8080/products/**1**

**when I added this param 1 after the /products**, the error went away.

( You Can try to use this accordingly to your project. )

Answer (score 0):

instead of sending request to `/restaurant/1/`, send it to `/restaurant/1`

Comment: This problem is not related to url issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need csrf you can do this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think your Model should implement Serializable interface and should have a default constructor.

For me issue was solved by adding above to my Model class and @RequestBody to the Controller method argument.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 405 Error Code is also returned IF the object cannot be deserialized, this happen as example with object without the default constructor.

take as example, this service :

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.resource.Singleton;

@Singleton
@Path("root")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class SampleRestService { ..
  @PUT
  @Path("sample")
  public void update(Sample whitelist) throws SampleException {
    // do some
}
```

and the Object sample, overriding the default constructor :

```
class Sample{
 int x,y;
 public sample(int x, int y){
   // boring stuff
 }
}
```

in this case de unmarshaling cannot deserialize the request content, and the 405 is triggered. Or at last that is how is working with glassfish 3.5 and javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar and jersey-xxx-2.25.1.jar.

The fix is actually add the default constructor (*ie. the one without parameters*) to the objects passed through the APIs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had to use a model class with `@RequestBody` for the patch controller.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got a right response with **post** instead of **put**.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue but later on, I got it corrected by rectifying the put mapping path in the backend server from `<@PutMapping("/user/{id} ")>` to `<@PutMapping("/user/{id}")>`. Make sure  there isn't a space after id;