# Why spring mvc put mapping method requests return redirect as put method

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

`Hi,` I am making my personal project like "teachable".

I confronted a problem.

I want to send PUT request to server and server redirect to other url(GET request).

1. Request "PUT /course/1/edit"
2. Server processes some logic and redirect to "GET /members/1/courses/manage"

However, Server didn't work.

Spring MVC ERROR message is `Request method 'PUT' not supported`.

Chrome Console ERROR is `PUT http://localhost:8080/members/1/courses/manage 405`

If request mapping is POST and GET not PUT, return redirect is working good.

I just wonder why PUT mapping return redirect requests redirect as PUT method.

Below, Spring MVC found view name "redirect:/members/1/courses/manage"
and redirect to "members/1/courses/manage" using PUT method. At this point, I can't understand why spring mvc use PUT method to redirection.

```
o.s.web.servlet.view.RedirectView        : View name 'redirect:/members/1/courses/manage', model {}
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : PUT "/members/1/courses/manage", parameters={}
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PUT' not supported]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
```

And if you know any document to help me about this problem, please recommend it to me.

Thanks in advance!

#### front code

```js
function courseEdit(courseUrl) {
    let formDataArray = $("#course-edit-form").serializeArray();
    let formDataObject = {};
    for (const element of formDataArray) {
        formDataObject[element.name] = element.value;
    }
    let courseEditFormDataJsonFormat = JSON.stringify(formDataObject);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: courseUrl,
        data: courseEditFormDataJsonFormat,
        contentType: 'application/json'
    }).done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {

    });
}
```

#### back code

```java
@PutMapping("/courses/{id}")
public String editCourse(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody CourseDto courseDto) {
        CourseDto foundCourseDto = courseService.findById(id);
        Long instructorId = foundCourseDto.getInstructor().getId();

        // redirect:/members/1/courses/manage
        return "redirect:/members/"+instructorId+"/courses/manage";
}

@GetMapping("/members/{id}/courses/manage")
public String courseDashboard(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
    CoursesDto ownCourse = courseService.findOwnCourse(id);
    model.addAttribute("coursesDto", ownCourse);
    return "course/course_dashboard";
}
```

Comment: there are several possible things to check in the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381402/http-status-405-request-method-put-not-supported

Comment: You didn't show the URL in question, but note that (1) you seem to be mixing a JSON-style API with a page-load API in a way that is guaranteed to cause you headaches and (2) the URL of the course resource is just `/courses/{id}`, and PUT communicates that you want to modify it without `edit`.

Comment: @AlexWittig Thanks for sharing the link

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Thanks, I updated my code using without `edit`. Can I know how to use JSON-style API with page-load API? Before this question, Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@PutRequest` is getting forwarded to `/members/{id}/courses/manage` which is a `@GetMapping`endpoint.

As [chrylis -on strike-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189885/chrylis-on-strike) pointed out, this is not how you should go about doing this.

You should do the redirect in the frontend after your ajax request is complete.
You can do this using `window.location`.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: courseUrl,
        data: courseEditFormDataJsonFormat,
        contentType: 'application/json'
    }).done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        // logic here to get {id} value
        window.location = "/members/{id}/courses/manage"
    });
```

Add the logic to enter the real id value in the request {id} from the input form.

Also on a side note, you have a hardcoded 1 in `return "redirect:/members/1/courses/manage";`

```
@PutMapping("/courses/{id}/edit")
public String editCourse(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody CourseDto courseDto) {
    return "redirect:/members/1/courses/manage";
}
```

Comment: @HardLearner Good deal - does the rest of the post answer your question or do you need more clarification?

Comment: Actually, I have a question. Why spring mvc redirects redirect url using PUT method. At PostMapping mehthod's redirection is working through GET. However, at PutMapping method's redirection is working through PUT. I updated debugging message related it. Can you check the first code block on my post? I just wonder why spring mvc is working on that way.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem, too. I have changed @GetMapping to @RequestMapping, in this way, It can work although it's redirected from a Put request. But when I'm eatting, I happen to wonder why it working like this.

Comment: I solve this problem. Keyword is "redirection", "HttpStatusCode:303(SEE OTHER)". I will write detail comment or answer about this in this weekend.