# Request method 'PUT' not supported When calling from Resttemplate

Tags: java, rest, resttemplate, put

I have to call a PUT method using Resttemplate. I am able to hit the service from POST Man. But when i try the same request from Java using Resttemplate its throwing error .What could be mistake i am doing.

```
405 : [{"category":"ACCESS","code":"METHOD_NOT_SUPPORTED","description":"Request method 'PUT' not 
supported","httpStatusCode":"405"}]

@Autowired
@Qualifier("orderMasterUpdateClient")
private RestTemplate orderMasterUpdateClient; // Loading the template with credentials and URL

ResponseEntity<SalesOrderDocument> responseEntity = orderMasterUpdateClient.exchange(
                URL,
                HttpMethod.PUT,
                new HttpEntity<>(headers),
                SalesOrderDocument.class, changeRequest);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'PUT' not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381402/http-status-405-request-method-put-not-supported)

Comment: can you provide the request executed through Postman in curl command format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send `changeRequest`object data in the body of the PUT request, I suggest you to use next RestTemplate exchange method call:

```
String url = "http://host/service";
ChangeRequest changeRequest = new ChangeRequest();
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
HttpEntity<ChangeRequest> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(changeRequest, httpHeaders);

ResponseEntity<ChangeRequest> response = restTemplate
            .exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT, httpEntity, ChangeRequest.class);
```