# restTemplate delete with body

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate, spring-rest

I am trying to do DELETE with request body but I keep getting 400 (bad request) error. When I do it in the swagger/postman, it is successfully deleting the record. But from the Java code I can't do that

The external API is designed in a way that it needs body along with URL. It can't be changed. please let me know how can I delete that entry with request body

```
public Person delete(Person person, String url, Map<String, String> uriVariables) throws JsonProcessingException {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        CustomObjectMapper mapper = new CustomObjectMapper();
        HttpEntity<Person> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Person>(person);
        try {
            ResponseEntity<Person> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, requestEntity, Person.class, uriVariables);
            return responseEntity.getBody();
        } catch (RestClientException e) {
            System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(person));
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

when it goes to exception, I will get the JSON request in JSON format and the same works fine in Swagger/postman

I did some googling and found that restTemplate have problem deleting when there is request body. this article wasn't helpful https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12361 is there any way to get it work

Comment: You already have a request body in `requestEntity`. Check your API and see what it's expecting. Then check if your body is serialized to what you expected.

Comment: the request body is same. the same body is working for POST and PUT. Delete worked fine from swagger UI with same values but it fails in java code

Comment: There isn't enough detail here for us to help you. Show us what gets sent over the wire for Swagger. Show us what gets sent for the`RestTemplate` example. At that point, you'll probably find your answer yourself.

Comment: I did CustomObjectMapper mapper = new CustomObjectMapper(); and debugging mapper.writeValueAsString(person) and the same request logged in by the java code works fine in Swagger UI. Wondering what would be the issue

Comment: The bug you linked to is fairly self-explanatory.  Spring on java <1.8 will not be able to send a body with a DELETE.  The issue is actually in java, not Spring.  I suspect this comes from a rather strict reading of the http spec, regardless, there's no way to get it to work short of moving to jdk 1.8, per the bug.

Answer (score 10):

Another way to fix this is to use `restTemplate.exchange`, here's an example:

```
try {
      String jsonPayload  = GSON.toJson(request);
      HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonPayload.toString(),headers());
      ResponseEntity resp = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, entity, String.class);
} catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
      /* Handle error */
}
```

The nice thing about this solution is that you can use it with all HttpMethod types.

Answer (score 5):

**Issue exists for Spring version 4.0.x or earlier.**
In later version it has been fixed.

This might be a late answer, but in one of my project I solved this issue via a custom `ClientHttpRequestFactory` to `RestTemplate`

If no factory is provided to `RestTemplate`, it uses default implementation [SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.0.x/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java)

In `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` class, `DELETE` method is not allowed with request body.

```
if ("PUT".equals(httpMethod) || "POST".equals(httpMethod) ||     
         "PATCH".equals(httpMethod)) {
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
}
else {
    connection.setDoOutput(false);
}
```

Just write your own implementation as

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

import org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory;

public class CustomClientHttpRequestFactory extends SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory {

    @Override
    protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, 
            String httpMethod) throws IOException {

        super.prepareConnection(connection, httpMethod);
        if("DELETE".equals(httpMethod)) {
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
        }
    }
}
```

After that create your `RestTemplate` object as

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(
                            new CustomClientHttpRequestFactory());
```

Fix in later versions of (**4.1.x or above**) `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` class

```
if ("POST".equals(httpMethod) || "PUT".equals(httpMethod) ||
            "PATCH".equals(httpMethod) || "DELETE".equals(httpMethod)) {
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
}
else {
    connection.setDoOutput(false);
}
```