# How to Pass a RequestBody in DeleteMethod in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to pass a request body to make a delete request in order to call a third-party API's delete Request. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375046/passing-data-in-the-body-of-a-delete-request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification RFC 7231 doesn't prevent from accepting a RequestBody in DELETE method.

```
A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a DELETE request might cause some existing  implementations to reject the request.
```

You can accept Request Body if the underlying web server is configured to parse the body for DELETE method.

Comment: I understand your point but I had to connect a 3rd party API which was designed the way I asked in my question.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found the way that I was searching for. The problem can be solved using Rest template

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpEntity<Model> request = new HttpEntity<>(new Model("data"));
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, request, null);
```